Boxed environment with several rows in its title
I'm a math teacher. I use MS Office to generate handouts like these one :

I need to display several informations in the header for referencing. I tried to replicate something similar in latex using tabular environment.
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{exercice}
  {
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|l|c|}\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{Coucou} & Partie & 2 \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & Séquence & 4 \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & Exercice & 6 \\ \hline
  }
  {
  \\\hline
  \endtabularx
  }
  
\begin{document}

\begin{exercice}\multicolumn{3}{|c|}
Hello world !
\[
x+y=z
\]
}
\end{exercice}

\end{document}

For now, it seems to be impossible to write a long paragraph with equations in a multicolumn command. How could I do this better ?
Would it be smart to use a tcolorbox for something similar ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your problem is \multicolumn{3}{|c|}, with that you're in horizontal mode in which you can't use displayed maths. Also in your MWE there is the opening brace after \multicolumn{3}{|c|} missing.

Can't you show the start of the exercise?

Some playground for boxes…
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercice}{mmmm+b}{%
  % #1=titre, #2=partie, #3=séquence, #4=exercice, #5=matériel
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8pt}%
  \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \framebox[\textwidth][s]{%
    \Large\bfseries\hspace*{0.5em}#1\hfill
    \raisebox{\dimeval{\depth-2\dp\strutbox}}{%
      \normalsize\normalfont
      \begin{tabular}{|l|c}
        \textbf{Partie} & #2 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Séquence} & #3 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Exercice} & #4
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \par\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip\vspace{-\fboxrule}
  \framebox[\textwidth]{%
    \parbox{\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}{#5}%
  }%
}{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{exercice}{Hello world !}{2}{F1}{2}
\[
x+y=z
\]
\end{exercice}

\begin{exercice}{Exercice de la fin du monde (suite)}{2}{F1}{2}
\[
x+y=z
\]
\end{exercice}

\end{document}


It's up to you to ensure that the title fits the allotted space.

Thanks ! It's very helpful !

The following defines an environment that only uses a tabular for the contents in the upper right corner. The rest is using \parbox or minipage. The advantage is that you aren't in any tabular like structure and hence don't need \multicolumn to get the full width and can simply use whatever LaTeX constructs you want inside your environment.
The result is not page breakable.
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\newsavebox\exerciseBox
\newsavebox\exerciseTab
\newenvironment{exercice}[4]
  {%
    \sbox\exerciseTab
      {%
        \bfseries\sffamily
        \begin{tabular}[c]{|l|c}
          Partie   & #2 \\
          Séquence & #3 \\
          Exercise & #4 \\
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
    \begin{lrbox}\exerciseBox
      \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule\relax}%
        \hfil % bit of padding (works because the nested contents are 2\tabcolsep shorter than the line)
        \parbox[c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\exerciseTab-2\tabcolsep}{\bfseries\sffamily\Large #1}%
        \hfil % bit of padding
        \usebox\exerciseTab
        \hrule % full width spanning horizontal rule
        \medskip % bit of padding below the rule
        \leavevmode\hfil % bit of padding to the left of the contents (again 2\tabcolsep shorter than the line)
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
  }
  {%
        \end{minipage}\hfil\null % bit of padding to the right of contents
        \medskip % bit of padding above the bottom delimiting rule
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \par
    \medskip % bit of whitespace above the contents
    \noindent
    \fboxsep=0pt % rules without padding (padding is already there, no additional `\fbox` padding wanted)
    \fbox{\usebox\exerciseBox}%
    \par
    \medskip % bit of whitespace below the contents
  }
  
\begin{document}

\begin{exercice}{Coucou}{2}{4}{6}
  Hello world !
  \[
    x+y=z
  \]
\end{exercice}

\end{document}



Thanks ! It's very helpful !

EDIT: With tabularray and tcolorbox.
\documentclass[french]{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercice}{mmmm+b}{%
% #1=titre, #2=partie, #3=séquence, #4=exercice, #5=matériel
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%<-- from egreg'answer
  \noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=white,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=.8pt,
    boxsep=0mm,
    top=0mm,leftupper=0mm,rightupper=0mm,
    lower separated=false,
    middle=1mm,%<--- 2mm default value
  ]
    \begin{tblr}
          {
            hlines,vlines,
            colspec     = { X[font=\Large\bfseries] 
                            Q[font=\bfseries]
                            Q[2em,c]},
            cell{1}{1}  = {r=3,c=1}{l},
          }
        #1  & Partie   & #2\\
            & Séquence & #3\\
            & Exercice & #4\\
        \end{tblr}
    \tcblower
    #5 
  \end{tcolorbox}
  }%
  {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}%<-- from egreg'answer
\begin{document}


\begin{exercice}{hello}{2}{3}{4}
  \[
  x+y=z
  \]
\end{exercice}

\begin{exercice}{Exercice de la fin du monde (suite)}{2}{F1}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{exercice}
\end{document}



Thanks ! It's very helpful ! However, it seems like the content of the environment is missing...

I should put on my glasses. I modified the answer with the (very interesting) tcolorbox package.

TeX works with boxes: \hbox, \vbox and lines are inserted by \vrule, \hrule. You can declare your environment using these TeX primitives:
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{exercice}[4] {%
   \vbox\bgroup
      \hrule
      \hbox\bgroup \vrule \vbox\bgroup
         \hbox to\hsize{\bfseries\sffamily\ \raise3ex\hbox{\Large #1}\hss
            \vrule\ \vbox{\medskip\hbox{Partie}\hbox{Séquence}\hbox{Excersise}\medskip} 
            \vrule\ \vbox{\hbox{#2}\hbox{#3}\hbox{#4}\medskip} }
         \hrule
         \vbox\bgroup
             \parindent=0pt \leftskip=.5em \rightskip=.5em \bigskip
}{%
             \medskip\egroup
      \egroup \vrule \egroup
      \hrule
   \egroup
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{exercice}{Coucou}{2}{4}{6}
  Hello world !
  \[
    x+y=z
  \]
\end{exercice}

\end{document}


Thanks ! It's very helpful ! I have to dig how boxes work in LaTeX !

@Froum If you interested in it, you can read a summary of basic TeX principles I wrote. It is TeX in a Nutshell, https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf . Section 7 is about box, kern, glue mechanism of TeX.
